# put csv data to array imacros js

Tags: web-scraping, imacros

I am trying to loop through a csv file pushing each column into an array but I am not sure how to do that, I know that the tag `{{!COL1}}` will give me the data I want but I can't figure out how to save it into a variable I can use to push inside an array.

```
csvToArray = "CODE:";
csvToArray += "SET !DATASOURCE artist.csv" + "\n";
csvToArray += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
csvToArray += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{CSV}}" + "\n";
csvToArray += "SET !VAR1 {{!COL1}}" + "\n";

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
iimSet("CSV", i);
iimPlay(csvToArray);
}
```

This code will allow me to loop through a csv file, and the `{{!COL1}}` tag gives me the data i want, how do i save this into a varialbe i can use, please someone help cant figure this one out. :(

Answer (score 0):

To get the data of COL1 you will need to set EXTRACT = COL1, then assign your variable to iimGetLastExtract().

Add this to your macro:

```
csvToArray += "SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}";
```

Then add this to your js file:

```
var myArray = []; // place at top of file for readability
myArray.push(iimGetLastExtract()); // place at end of for loop
                                   // puts each extraction into myArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code block.

```
function read_file(path) {
var content = '', i = 1, f, res = '',spl;

 while (1){
    content = res;      
    if (content != "") {
    spl = content.split("|"); 
    //spl[0] will contain the Row1 and Column1 value, spl[1] will contain Row 1 and Column 2 value etc.,
    /*Here you can specify your script/conditions
    Example:
    iimPlay('CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:login[username] CONTENT='+spl[0]);
    iimPlay('CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD ATTR=NAME:login[password] CONTENT='+spl[1]);

I used the infinite loop, so in order to come out of the loop, you need to add a condition like below

if (spl[0]=="End") {//In your input sheet if the Row1,Col1 contains the value 'End', then it will exit the loop
        iimDisplay("All Rows Completed");
        return;
    }   

    */ 
    f = "CODE: "+"\n";
    f += "SET !EXTRACT null" + "\n"; 
    f += "SET !LOOP 3" + "\n"; 
    f += "SET !DATASOURCE \""+path+"\" "+"\n";
    f += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 5" + "\n"; //Assume that you have five columns in the your input file
    f += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE " + i + "\n"; 
    f += "SET !EXTRACT {{!col1}}|{{!col2}}|{{!col3}}|{{!col4}}|{{!col5}}" + "\n";
    iimPlay(f);        
    res = iimGetLastExtract();
    i++;
}
return content;
}
var file_conten = read_file("yourinputfilename.csv");
```